# Custom RecyclerView Adapter not refreshing the view notifyDataSetChange

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I wrote below code about in two weeks. I really want to learn and I'm trying.

I can't get why my adapter doesn't update when `notifyDataChange()` method called.

In the logcat, I can see my `FilterResult` was changed as I write the searching text. I can see the new list of items are in the filtered list.

Can you make my way a little easier?

---

```
open class MainAdapter (val coins: Array<Coin>, activity: Activity): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() , Filterable {

var resultList : Array<Coin>? = coins
val activity : Activity = activity

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(sText: CharSequence?): Filter.FilterResults {
            val filterResults = Filter.FilterResults()
            if (sText != null) {
                println("--------- "+sText.toString()+" ---------")

                resultList = coins.filter {
                    it.symbol.contains(sText,true)
                }.toTypedArray()

                for(i in resultList!!.indices)
                    println("***coin $i: "+resultList!![i].symbol+" = "+resultList!![i].price_usd)

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList
                filterResults.count = resultList?.size ?: 0
            }
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(sText: CharSequence?,
                                    results: FilterResults?) {
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            println("notified")
        }
    }
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val li = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val cFR = li.inflate(R.layout.main_row,parent,false)
    return CustomViewHolder(cFR)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return resultList!!.count()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int){

    val coin = resultList!![position]
// Something..
    holder.coin = coin
}

 class CustomViewHolder (val view: View, var coin:Coin?=null):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){...}
```

---

```
`private fun jsonFetch(){
    val url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0"
    val baglanti = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val tarayici = OkHttpClient()
    tarayici.newCall(baglanti).enqueue(object : Callback{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            snackBar("No connection!")
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            coinList = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson (body,Array<Coin>::class.java)
            fillList(coinList!!)

        }
    })
}

fun fillList(c : Array<Coin>){
    runOnUiThread {
        mainView.adapter = MainAdapter(c,this)
        snackBar("Refreshed Data..")
    }
}
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)

    val search = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
    val searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search) as SearchView
    search(searchView)
    return true
}
private fun search(searchView: SearchView) {
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object:SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(sText: String): Boolean {
            MainAdapter(coinList!!,MainActivity()).filter.filter(sText)
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: hi, where are you seting the adapter ?, go to your mainactivity or where you are seting the adapter and where you are trying to refresh it

Comment: `private fun search(searchView: SearchView) {

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : 
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(sText: String): Boolean {
                MainAdapter(coinList!!,MainActivity()).filter.filter(sText)
                return true
            }
        })
    }`

Comment: please edit your question with that code, its more readable

Comment: also you need the piece where you have .setAdapter(adapter); or something like that, post your entire MainActivity, thanks

Comment: I call jsonFetch from inside OnCreate

Answer (score 0):

you can define adapter class like below sample code ...

```
class HeroAdapter(val item: MutableList<Hero>, val context: Context, val itemClick:OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HeroAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false)
    return ItemViewHolder(v)

}

var onClickListener: OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener? = null

open interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
    fun click(hero: Hero)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    var hero: Hero = item[position]
    onClickListener=itemClick
    holder?.mTvName?.text = hero.getName()
    holder?.mTvBio?.text = hero.getBio()
    holder?.mTvReal?.text = hero.getRealname()
    holder?.mTvFirst?.text = hero.getFirstappearance()
    holder?.mTvTeam?.text = hero.getTeam()
    holder?.mTvPublisher?.text = hero.getPublisher()
    holder?.mTvCreate?.text = hero.getCreatedby()
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(hero.getImageurl())
            .into(holder?.mIvImage)
    holder?.itemView?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        this.onClickListener?.click(hero)
    })
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return item.size
}

class ItemViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    var mTvName: TextView? = null
    var mTvReal: TextView? = null
    var mTvCreate: TextView? = null
    var mTvBio: TextView? = null
    var mTvTeam: TextView? = null
    var mTvPublisher: TextView? = null
    var mTvFirst: TextView? = null
    var mIvImage: ImageView? = null

    constructor(itemView: View) : super(itemView) {
        mTvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alTvName)
        mTvReal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alTvRealName)
        mTvFirst = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alTvFirst)
        mTvCreate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alTvcreatedby)
        mTvBio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alTvBio)
        mTvTeam = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alTvTeam)
        mTvPublisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alTvpublisher)
        mIvImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alIvUserImage)
    }
}
```

}

then after you can esally to notify adapter like below code ..

```
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I'm trying to filter via SearchView. So I coludn't do this way.

Comment: if you want only search functionlity implement then used edittext box and make background like search view and used edittext box  below method  mEtSearchData.addTextChangedListener(). and is working.

Comment: I edited the question. I add my main activity to the question. As you see, i make my search view work and when i input some text to the search view, i can see the filtered list from logcat screen. But there is no changing in the ui on the phone screen.